# Convert XML to Object with JAXB when node contains value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have worked previously with JAXB but I never faced an XML where nodes contained values. Like this one:

```
<node1>
  <node2 id="abc"/>
</node1>
```

I did treat node1 as @XmlRootElement and then I used a list of Node2 objects annotated with @XmlElement. In Node2 object I have created a String variable 'id' as below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "node1")
public class Node1{

  @XmlElement(name="node2")
  private List<Node2> node2list;

  //get-set
}

public class Node2{

  private String id;

  //get-set
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to get the value of node2. It always gives null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no value inside the `node2` element, that's why you're getting `null`, `id` is attribute in `node2` and you have to use `@XmlAttribute` to get the value of `id`.